# Setting the connection string dynamically in the health monitoring section of the webconfig

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to set the connections string dynamically in the health montitoring section of the web config?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, Web Configs are XML Documents so you access them like XML documents.
oXMLDoc will be your Web Config file which can be extracted by System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("web.config"); or  ((Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()).GetName()).Name + ".exe.config"

```
private String GetNodeValue(ref XmlDocument oXMLDoc, String sPath)
{
    String sValue = "";
    XmlNode oNode = oXMLDoc.SelectSingleNode(sPath);
    if (oNode != null)
    {
        sValue = oNode.InnerText.Trim();
    }
    return sValue;
}

private void SetNodeValue(ref XmlDocument oXMLDoc, String sPath, String sValue)
{
    XmlNode oNode = oXMLDoc.SelectSingleNode(sPath);
    if (oNode != null)
    {
        oNode.InnerText = sValue;
    }
}
```